# React Hooks create Failure: Type Error object (...) ist not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, typeerror

I want to use React hooks in particular to be able to use useContext hook.

As this didn't work I went into detail and figured out, that none of the React hooks is working, the failure is always the same. I have followed several postings, in particular updated everything to the latest version. Nevertheless: the failure remains the same.

Here is the code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// if I mark useState and/ or useEffect as comment everything works. 
// If one or both are active I get the error "TypeError: Object (...) ist not a function"
// I have updated and use react@16.13.1   react-dom@16.13.1

function Test() {

  //const [count, setCount] = useState(0); // this time useState is set as comment
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("I am in useEffect")
  });
  
  console.log("I am in Test")
  
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Use Effect has worked</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Test;
```

And the failure

[image: Here the "original" failure.]

Comment: Ciao, what version of react you are using? Can you post your package.json?

Comment: If you installed the right react and react-dom veriosn , do a fresh start of the UI server

Comment: @simbathesailor : that did it! I restarted the server and it works! Thx

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito: Thx. the version is 16.13.1 but the restart of the server was the solution

Comment: Oh ok. Well, I'm happy that you solved. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, the problem is in react version you are using. Hooks were added in v16.8, so `useState` and `useEffect` in your code is undefined. Unfortunately `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function` didn't get you a useful information.

Try to install react 16.8 and problem should be solved.